# How to PATCH or DELETE from a form without javascript

Tags: phoenix-framework

I am writing a simple crud app on Phoenix. How does one submit PATCH and DELETE requests from a form without using javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers

Comment: @Barmar this is a phoenix specific question

Comment: If it depends on what the browser supports in `<form>`, I don't think the framework matters.

Comment: @Barmar - not so, the question is really how can one tell Phoenix to ignore the explicit verb (POST) and use PATCH instead.  Rails made a particular convention popular (use _method to override the verb) so it's a reasonable bet that Phoenix did something similar but maybe not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah I figured it out, same as rails:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" />
...
```

Handled in Plug.MethodOverride: https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/master/lib/plug/method_override.ex

Comment: Check out @Barmar's comment, not all browsers are supported — some only understand GET and POST. Rails for example uses a hidden form  field `_method` as a workaround.

Comment: @PatrickOscity, not trying to be rude at all but my question presupposes the fact that browsers don't all natively support methods other than GET and POST, and the answer that you commented on plainly states that not only did I figure it out but that I am using the exact same workaround used in rails. I feel like neither you nor Bamar took the time to actually read what my question or answer were. :/ I was asking for a Phoenix specific solution... and I found it.

Comment: Isn't this solution what the first answer in the question I linked to suggests?

Comment: @greggreg sorry for that. Indeed it seems I did not read your answer properly. Maybe it's a bit too early in the morning. I just saw the input element and skipped the rest of the line. Your approach is perfectly fine!

Comment: @Barmar the first answer of the question you linked to simply states that many browsers support only GET and POST, that some frameworks have workarounds (which was my actual specific question) and that AJAX requests support other HTTP verbs.

Comment: easy enough, its the same as rails

Answer (score 4):

`<form>` elements only support sending `GET` and `POST` requests. The workaround that Rails uses is to read the request method from the `_method` request parameter, overriding the actual request method (the `GET` or `POST` method).

Phoenix does exactly the same through [Plug](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug), the Rack-like framework that Phoenix is built on. Long story short, Plug provides middlewares and one of the middlewares it provides is [`Plug.MethodOverride`](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.MethodOverride.html), which does exactly what we discussed. Doing so in a middleware, the Phoenix app barely knows that the original request was not a `GET`/`POST`.

You can see `Plug.MethodOverride` used [in Phoenix's source code](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/e22a9c48f33117051920ba535eb7202a5c4b5a2e/priv/template/lib/application_name/endpoint.ex).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the doc links. Helped me find the source: https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/master/lib/plug/method_override.ex

Answer (score 4):

As the others have mentioned, Phoenix handles this in the routing via the `MethodOverride` plug.

In order to change this in the template with the `form_for` helper, use the `:method` parameter:

`<%= form_for @changeset, path(@conn, :update), [multipart: true, method: "patch"], fn f -> %>`

This will add the hidden input to the HTML, as noted by @greggreg:

`<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" />`