# How to correctly use Plug.Override Method in phoenix to enable :delete without Javascript?

Tags: javascript, elixir, crud, phoenix-framework

I am trying to create a Javascript-free app (don't ask why...) and have run into the apparently common problem of the `:delete` method not working.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164132/how-to-patch-or-delete-from-a-form-without-javascript#) which told me I have to use [Plug.MethodOverride](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.MethodOverride.html).

So, I have added

```
plug Plug.Parser, parsers [:urlencoded, :multipart]
plug Plug.MethodOverride
```

to the Html pipeline in `routers.ex` (I am guessing I should probably move it to somewhere more specific later, but for now, I just wanted it to work quickly). However, the form generated by the resources helper still does not do anything. Do I have to change it to something else? Or am I missing a step in adding the Plug

Comment: Have you added the `method: :delete` to `form_for` as mentioned in an answer in that question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36273932/320615?

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me into the right direction, I had been confused since I did not know link_to generates a form_for underneath.

do you mind me posting the exact thing I did as an answer and accepting it for other complete newbies like me?

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Dogbert for pointing me in the right direction in the docs, I had not understood that link_to has an underlying form_for. To make it work I replaced the <% link_to ..%> by the following code

```
<%= form_for @conn, model_path(@conn, :delete, model), [multipart: true, method: "delete", as: :custom_delete], fn f -> %>
    <%= submit "Delete_nojs" %>
<% end %>
```

with

```
plug Plug.Parser, parsers [:urlencoded, :multipart]
plug Plug.MethodOverride
```

in the router pipeline this enables the method override.